# Click on text using xpath and selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Normally I use the xpath to click on text of webpages. But now maybe because it's a table it doesnt work. I want to click on "SNOW Microsoft 2019-03-26.csv" text that is unique in the table. My code is:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='grdReports']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").click()
```

Error: can't find the xpath

HTML looks like:

[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element with **grdReports** id is a **div**, not **table**:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='grdReports']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").click()
```

Also you can try shorter xpath:

```
//*[@id='grdReports']//tr[@role='row']/td[3]
```

Css selector:

```
#grdReports tr[role=row] > td:nth-child(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath:

```
//table[@role='grid']//tbody/tr/td[text()='SNOW Microsoft 2019-03-26.csv']
```

*Note: i am not sure if there is two spaces between Microsoft and 2019*

Answer (score 1):

I would just use

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'SNOW Microsoft 2019-03-26')]").click()
```